# Comparing React Native TTS and STT tools

Tags: react-native, speech-recognition

I have a React Native mobile app and want to add Speech Recognition to it ( Compatible with both IOS and android). I searched the web for all the possible tools and found the followings:

For Speech to Text(STT):

```
1.react-native-voice

2.RNSpeakChat

3.Using Google Cloud

4.SpeechRecognizer

5.react-native-watson 

6.react-speech-recognition

7.react-native-speech-recognition
```

and for text to speech (TTS):

```
1.react-native-tts

2.react-native-watson

3.react-native-speech
```

Now I need to compare these options; perhaps in terms of speed, accuracy, flexibility (ie., accents), bandwidth, integration with React Native, sound quality (TTS), limitations, restrictions, etc. Does any body has any good reference for this comparison?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

I am tried some STT libraries on your list.

**1.react-native-voice**
=> nice. free offline ok. but depends on system module.

2.RNSpeakChat
=> not tried

3.Using Google Cloud
=> it is not free and online

4.SpeechRecognizer
=> react-native-speech-recognizer is only for Chinese and English

5.react-native-watson
=> it is IBM stt service, like google cloud service.

6.react-speech-recognition
=> not for react native. it is for react web.

7.react-native-speech-recognition
=> not working